# Oracle: PL/SQL Procedure involving two different Schema in two different Databases

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, database-schema

I got a scenario like this, I have an existing procedure that looks similar to this.

```
PROCEDURE A_DATA_B( p_ID IN SCHEMA1.TABLE1.ID%TYPE,
                    p_MATCH IN SCHEMA1.TABLE2.MATCH%TYPE, 
                    p_STATUS IN SCHEMA1.TABLE3.STATUS%TYPE,  
                    p_MSG IN SCHEMA1.TABLE1.MSG%TYPE, 

                    The list goes on...
```

The SCHEMA1 was residing in the same database previously. Now this needs to be moved to another database in different server as such. But the schema name goes to be different but the Table name and the column name remain the same.

So I changed the procedure to look like this

```
PROCEDURE A_DATA_B( p_ID IN SCHEMA2.TABLE1.ID%TYPE,
                    p_MATCH IN SCHEMA2.TABLE2.MATCH%TYPE, 
                    p_STATUS IN SCHEMA2.TABLE3.STATUS%TYPE,  
                    p_MSG IN SCHEMA2.TABLE1.MSG%TYPE, 

                    The list goes on..
```

But when I compile I got the error

> PLS-00201: identifier 'SCHEMA2.TABLE1' must be declared PL/SQL:
>   Declaration ignored

I can understand from this error that SCHEMA2 is not in the database which gives the error. So How should I tackle it?
In the package body where ever am using this SCHEMA2 has been followed by an @db_link. So can I make use of that db_link to solve this?

By looking in to some article I came to know that SYNONYM can also be used. So is this the right way to create a synonym will work?

```
CREATE SYNONYM SCHEMA2 FOR SCHEMA2@db_link;
```

Can Someone help me in this regards.

Notes : I may not be able to convert the %type to varchar2 or numbers etc..

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 1):

Synonyms are created for objects, not schemas.

You can create synonyms for each table (object, view, etc.) in the local database and use that to declare your anchored types.

```
CREATE SYNONYM schema2.table1 
   FOR schema1.table1@db_link

CREATE SYNONYM schema2.table2 
   FOR schema1.table2@db_link

CREATE SYNONYM schema2.table3 
   FOR schema1.table3@db_link
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is helpful. But I got two replies. I want to know which will be good for performance.
using like this 
PROCEDURE A_DATA_B( p_ID IN SCHEMA2.TABLE1.ID@DBLINK_NAME%TYPE,
or using SYNONYM as you told?
or creating a reference set of tables in a schema on the current database, to be the source for the data types?

Comment: @justin_cave : Whats your opinion about creating a reference set of tables in a schema on the current database, to be the source for the data types? Is this methodology advisable?

Comment: @Krish - That would not be advisable.  It has no benefits over either synonyms or explicitly using the database link in the anchored type definitions.  And it creates the potential that the two sets of objects will get out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

The `%TYPE` referencing items you use as subprogram parameters can point to remote objects through a Database Link by adding the `@DBLINK_NAME` clause, e.g.:

```
PROCEDURE A_DATA_B( p_ID IN SCHEMA2.TABLE1.ID@DBLINK_NAME%TYPE,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to know which will be good for performance.
using like this 
PROCEDURE A_DATA_B( p_ID IN SCHEMA2.TABLE1.ID@DBLINK_NAME%TYPE,
OR using SYNONYM as in the above answer? 
Or 
creating a reference set of tables in a schema on the current database, to be the source for the data types?

Comment: A synonym is just an alternative name for an object, hence using a synonym will not provide better performances than referencing the object through its fully qualified name. However, depending on your environment, it may have other benefits like location transparency.